# Can I have formulas in a Google Form, not just the worksheet?

Tags: google-forms, formulas

We use a Google Form for registration for our charity road race.  I need to have two fields that contain formulas so people registering do not have to do the calculating.

1. They can order t-shirts.  Cost per shirt is $15. I need the next field to calculate the money they owe, so they don't make mistakes (i.e., 4 shirts x $15 = $60).
2. People can donate additional money so I need a field that will add the amount owed for t-shirts with any additional money donated, and reflect the grand total owed.

Is this possible?  If not, do you have any suggestions for a way to do with with another application?  Can forms like Google Forms be created with Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 1):

> do you have any suggestions for a way to do with with another
>   application?

This is possible with our product, [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com). Please see [How To Add Options in a Payment Form](http://www.jotform.com/help/225-How-To-Add-Options-In-The-Payment-Form) tutorial for details.

The tutorial assumes you already know how to use JotForm so first do these steps:

1. Go to JotForm site and create an account
2. Create a new form
3. Add "Purchase Order" field to the form. It is under Payment Tools on the form builder. ("Purchase Order" just means a product calculation field with no actual integration with a payment gateway such as PayPal or Stripe.)
4. Now, you can follow the instructions on the tutorial to setup quantity and t-shirt sizes.

You also asked about adding a donation amount to the calculated value. To accomplish that you can use the [calculate field feature](http://www.jotform.com/answers/293534-How-to-use-Calculate-Field-option).

If you have any further questions let me know.